# How to structure chat messages in supabase database?

Tags: postgresql, chat, supabase, supabase-database

There are many questions available for the firebase chat structure.

But I cant figure out how to structured in supabase.

As I think,

case 1:
In one table store every message of all chat room. In this case billions of row will inserted of message.

case 2:
create table named (unique id of chat room of two users) of each chat room. In this case many tables will created in project.

case 3:
suggestion of other structure

Comment: Case 1, using table partitioning, partitioned by something (could be the chatroom-id, but also per month or something else) would be my first shot when expecting billions of records.

Comment: in case 1 , how to store messages of two users in one column?

Comment: I have a table for channels and another for messages. But this question depends on implementation/scope decisions and it is not suited to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can take this as an inspiration, goes more into case 1 direction:

https://supabase.com/blog/flutter-tutorial-building-a-chat-app
https://supabase.com/blog/flutter-authentication-and-authorization-with-rls